# Angular2 / PrimeNG datatable using trackBy and ngModel stops updating

Tags: angular, primeng, ngrx

I'm using a component bound with [ngModel] in a PrimeNG datatable component using trackBy based on a ngrx-store architecture. The introduction of trackBy resolved an issue where all inputs triggered a reload on the ngFor-based datatable.

However, while the ngModel reference works fine for the first initialization, I can no longer properly access it to update its value. Snippet:

Template:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="(data$ | async).Channels" [rowTrackBy]="identify">
    <p-column field="active" header="Active">
        <template let-entry="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
            <p-checkbox (click)="updateValue({channel: entry, field: 'active', value: !entry.active })" [ngModel]="entry.active" binary="true"></p-checkbox>
        </template>
</p-column>
... 
</p-datatable>
```

Referenced trackBy function:

```
identify(index, channel) {
    return channel.id;
}
```

`!entry.active` will now always have the initial value, any ideas?